# SPFx - How to know if a user is in the context of a document set

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, document-set

We want to display custom menu buttons in a document set. We haven't found a solution, through SPFx, which gives us information that the user is inside a document set. Neither Url or _sppageContextInfo object contains this information.

If there any way to get this information through SPFx?

Comment: are you using a classic view or a modern view?

Comment: I am using a modern view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [Anita](https://www.itidea.nl/index.php/spfx-associate-listview-command-set-to-a-content-type/) has a viable suggestion described in her article. It's not the prettiest, but it seems to be working.

Basically you check:

- if your current list contains a specific content type. In your case it's Document set
- check if the currently selected document has a specific content type. In your case it's a document.

The full article is here: [SPFx associate listview command set to a content type](https://www.itidea.nl/index.php/spfx-associate-listview-command-set-to-a-content-type/).